# Download file directly from URL to local folder or a folder in remote server

Tags: php, parsing, download, email-attachments, mailgun

I have download a file from the link & has to save in my local system folder or in a remote server folder. The scenario is that: I have a mailgun domain, when I send a mail to it, Mailgun store function (`store()`) stores it with all attachments & notifies me. The response from mailgun is catched in `catch_email_attachment()`, I'm able fetch the response & got the link of attached files. When I run the link directly in browser it gives me the attached file, no problem on that. But I need to download the file inside `catch_email_attachment()` & to save it in a folder.

The downloadable file is as: "`https://API:<API-KEY>@api.mailgun.net/v2/domains/sandboxa6e6ebce3f68475aa3xxxxxxxd60.mailgun.org/messages/eyJwIjogZmFsc2UsICJrIjogImQ0MmZjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDQwNy1iYzhlLTA2OWMxY2U3MDg2NCIsIxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1Y2UiLCAiYyI6ICJpYWR0cmFpbGVycyJ9/attachments/0`"

My codes are below:

```
public function catch_email_attachment()
{
    $data = $this->input->post(null, true);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        if (isset($data['attachments'])) {
            /*
            Output of $data['attachments'] is below:
            [{"url": "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/domains/sandboxa6e6ebce3f68475aa3xxxxxxxd60.mailgun.org/messages/eyJwIjogZmFsc2UsICJrIjogImQ0MmZjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDQwNy1iYzhlLTA2OWMxY2U3MDg2NCIsIxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1Y2UiLCAiYyI6ICJpYWR0cmFpbGVycyJ9/attachments/0", "content-type": "image/jpeg", "name": "xxxxxxx.jpeg", "size": 9498}]
            */

            copy('https://API:key-e5ae9afab1fa9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxa95a@api.mailgun.net/v2/domains/sandboxa6e6ebce3f68475axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages/eyJwIjogZmFsc2UxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmUtNDQwNy1iYzhlLTA2OWMxY2U3MDg2NCIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1Y2UiLCAiYyI6ICJpYWR0cmFpbGVycyJ9/attachments/0', '/var/www/download_loc/');
        }
    }
}
```

I have refered:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26330976/4229270

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594030/4229270

https://stackoverflow.com/a/724449/4229270

Can you help me to solve the issue... Thanking in advance.

Comment: swap `copy` for `file_get_contents` and you're done

Comment: Huh, turns out `copy` does in fact handle URLS. I see your problem, though. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Farkie- waiting for your answer, I have checked with 'file_get_contents', not solved. hope you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$data['attachments']` is a json array so you need something like:

```
    $attachments = json_decode($data['attachments']);
        $api_key = 'APIKEY';
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

                $context = stream_context_create(array(
                    'http' => array(
                        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("API:$api_key")
                    )
                ));

                file_put_contents('/var/www/download_loc/' . $attachment->name, file_get_contents($attachment->url, false, $context));

            }
        }
```

Comment: yes, $data['attachments'] its a jsode data. I have also checked your code, but not solved. And, if I run "$attachment->url" in browser as I said earlier, the file gets downloaded.

Comment: i have also set folder permissions, still it does not goes well.

Comment: Hi Sinto, I've checked and my code definitely does what you'd expect. Don't you need to add the `API:<API-KEY>@` part?

Comment: Ya, I have added it while checking. Still not worked

Comment: Still not, Is there anything wrong in my local path?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is surly helpful for me. What I have done & got is:

Mailgun will give response to our hook function which we set in our maingun domain. Catch the response from Mailgun as:

```
$data = $this->input->post(null, true);
$attachments = json_decode($data['attachments']);
$apikey = 'API:<API_KEY>@';
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    $st = strpos($attachment->url, 'https://');
    if ($st !== false) {
        $attachment->url = str_replace('https://', 'https://'.$apikey, $attachment->url);
        $temp_name = $attachment->name;
        $file_path = '<PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD>'.$temp_name;
        copy($attachment->url, $file_path); // Downloading file to our path
    }
}
```

You have to check endpoint from Mailgun response. And, have to set respective in or code. Also, we have to set *API KEY* & *PATH TO DOWNLOAD*.

The storage link from Mailgun will be to "xx.api.mailgun.net" over "api.mailgun.net". It will be like "si.api.mailgun.net", "so.api.mailgun.net", "se.api.mailgun.net", "sw.api.mailgun.net", etc.. The URL to obtain the attachment data would be

Eg: https://API:key-60mvxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@sw.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/YOUR_MAILGUN_DOMAIN/messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=/attachments/0

The data returned from the API will return the URL to obtain the stored message : (items > attachments > url)

Please refer: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#retrieving-stored-messages

Comment: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#retrieving-stored-messages